# GIT fatal: unable to write new_index file

Tags: git, git-commit, git-add

I interrupted a `git add -A` command using `Ctrl+C`
and then I run

```
git reset --mixed
```

Now I executed again `git add -A` 
and then `git commit -m "message"`
but I get

`fatal: unable to write new_index file`

The output of

```
git status:

# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Can you help me in committing my changes?

ps I have enough space in my disk

Comment: Would this help? On what OS are you? What version of git are you using?

Comment: I'm running Linux. git version 1.7.1

Comment: First, check if the issue persists after upgrading to the latest Git release (2.1+): http://stackoverflow.com/a/20918469/6309: use the ppa https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I can't update it on this machine (linux cluster...I don't have permissons) anyway I used git since a while now and this is the first time I had this problem...

Comment: Then try to clone the repo again, and try from that new clone a `git add --work-tree=/path/to/old/repo -A`, followed by (still from the new clone) a `git commit -m "message"` (no `--work-tree` this time)

Comment: the output of git status is: nothing to commit (working directory clean)...can it help?

Comment: Not really: simply try a new clone, and add what was in the old clone, to see if the error persists.

Comment: I get close error: Disk quota exceeded...but I have 41.3 GB in my HD

Answer (score 2):

The error seems to be linked to a quota issue.

```
Disk quota exceeded
```

> ...but I have 41.3 GB in my HD

This isn't linked to the free disk space. Check your quota with `quota -s`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found that it was a file permissions issue. I had created the repository with a different user, and when I tried to any actions in git I was getting "Permission denied" of fetch and "unable to write new_index file".

Therefore, check the permissions of the root directory of the repository and make sure that the user has permissions to write to that directory