# Getting fatal error on push and clone the git

Tags: git

I was able to push and pull from the git remote till yesterday. I don't know (or remember) what I did today suddenly I can't push to remote git repo. I am getting following error

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 83, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (16/16), done.
Writing objects: 100% (17/17), 1.32 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 17 (delta 12), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: fatal: unresolved deltas left after unpacking
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To //myserver/git/apps/myApp.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to '//myserver/git/apps/myApp.git'
```

And when I try to clone again I am getting error

```
$ Git clone //myserver/git/apps/myApp.git/
Cloning into 'MyApp'...
done.
fatal: unable to read tree 18295307f1270da3c09e3de91890652af4ff7ca8
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'
```

Both

```
git status
```

and

```
git checkout -f HEAD
```

gives error

```
fatal: unable to read tree 18295307f1270da3c09e3de91890652af4ff7ca8
```

Can anyone help me understand what went  wrong and how can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to diagnose and fix git fatal: unable to read tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870895/how-to-diagnose-and-fix-git-fatal-unable-to-read-tree)

Comment: I got a similar problem (while clonning the repo , not while pushing) and upon further analysis I found that I have a file with the same name in the same directory path , but different in case. Somebody pushed it from a linux dev machine and I was trying to clone it into windows.

Comment: I clone in new fresh directory and still same fatal error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved this issue. Luckily my remote repo is up to date  with no error. With verify object command

```
git fsck --full
```

I saw the dangling tree. So I wen to the server and copy those missing object to my local copy. With continuous check and copy I am able to bring all missing object and finally able to push. Evey thing is up to date now.

Reason  to corrupt my local copy may be I delete the branch. Which I have done.