# GIT unable to read file it compressed

Tags: git

I'm attempting to push changes with git via `git push production master` and it compresses the files to push and then gives me these errors in return:

```
Counting objects: 1861, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1808/1808), done.
fatal: unable to read 58926d52844e79d28435d8ea82bd8c7107e01a48
remote: fatal: early EOF
```

I'm having a hard time understanding why the compression is failing, or if that's what's happening at all.

Comment: It's not clear the compression is the problem.  The error is `unable to read 58926d52844e79d28435d8ea82bd8c7107e01a48`.  Where is the destination repository? Is it on a server you control, or on a hosted service like github/gitlab/bitbucket/etc?

Comment: It's hosted by WPEngine who swear the issue isn't on their end. Pushes perfectly fine to bitbucket so I suspect it's on their end. Just can't get them to understand that.

Comment: Have you tried some of the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870895/how-to-diagnose-and-fix-git-fatal-unable-to-read-tree) to rule out problems with your local repository?

Answer (score 1):

This is rather puzzling.  If the problem were remote, I would expect to see:

```
remote: fatal: unable to read <hash>
```

but the actual output is:

```
fatal: unable to read <hash>
```

which I believe means that it's your own Git—in this case, your `builtin/pack-objects.c` file—that is complaining [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ccdcbd54c4475c2238b310f7113ab3075b5abc9c/builtin/pack-objects.c#L127-L133):

```
        buf = read_object_file(&entry->idx.oid, &type, &size);
        if (!buf)
                die("unable to read %s", oid_to_hex(&entry->idx.oid));
        base_buf = read_object_file(&entry->delta->idx.oid, &type, &base_size);
        if (!base_buf)
                die("unable to read %s",
                    oid_to_hex(&entry->delta->idx.oid));
```

This could perhaps be coming from the fancy new "promise objects" code that allows partial clones to exist.  See [the partial clone documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/partial-clone.txt) for details.  Is your clone unusual in any way, e.g., shallow?  (Does `.git/shallow` exist?)  What version of Git are you running?  (Promise objects and narrow clones have partial support as of Git 2.17, using the "filter" options.)

The fact that [you can push to a different server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50240399/git-unable-to-read-file-it-compressed#comment87499788_50240399) is not, itself, all that important, since the delta bases *your* Git will use when compressing a pack file to send on `git push` depends on which commits *their* Git has.  If the two servers have different sets of commits on them, your own Git may choose different delta-bases with which to build the thin pack to send to their Git.